# How can one explain this seemingly inconsistent Java varargs behavior?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, variadic-functions

If I write the Java method

```
public static void f(int... x) {
    for (int a: x) {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

then I can call this method via

```
f(1, 2, 3);
```

as well as

```
f(new int[]{1, 2, 3});
```

and both calls are treated exactly the same.  However, the two calls

```
Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)              // (a) produces a three-element Integer list
```

and

```
Arrays.asList(new int[]{1, 2, 3})   // (b) produces a one-element list of Integer arrays
```

are not treated the same.  [The section on evaluating arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4.2) in the JLS states "The final formal parameter of *m* necessarily has type `T[]` for some `T`" so why isn't the "final formal parameter" in case (b) above *not* an integer array which would create a three-element list, like case (a)?

The only thing I can think of is that `Arrays.asList` is generic, and *something* about type compatibility (mentioned in JLS Section 15.12.4.2) is at play here, but I can't quite put my finger on the actual sentence in the JLS that makes the two cases different.

The commentary in the JLS talks about the need to craft these semantics carefully in order to handle the interplay between "parameterized types and array types that occurs in a Java Virtual Machine with erased generics" but what we end up is my function `f` and `Arrays.asList` appearing to behave inconsistent.  In the former case I can "unpack" or "pack" my args and all is the same; in the latter case, the two cases are different.

How is this explained in language-lawyer terms?

Comment: I have a feeling you can reproduce the apparent inconsistency with `public static void f(Object... x)` or `public T static void f(T... x)` .. *(not at a comp now so can't try)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Arrays.asList` is defined as having parameter `T...`, and the body will see it as one argument of type `T[]`.  However, `T` *must be a reference type* (like any type parameter), and `int` is not a reference type.  Because of that, there's no way to make `new int[]{...}` compatible with an array for varargs purposes.  (And the result would be `List<int>` which isn't allowed.)  The only alternative is to treat it as a single object, and thus `T` here will be `int[]`, which is a reference type, and the function will return a `List<int[]>`.

I think that's the reason, although I would still need to look up the exact language.  It probably involves the type inference rules, which I haven't mastered.

However, I did try this:

```
List x = Arrays.asList(new int[]{1, 2, 3});
List y = Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3});
System.out.println(x.size());   
System.out.println(y.size());
```

(note that I deliberately used a `List` raw type, something I wouldn't do in real code).  The output:

```
1
3
```

Comment: I agree, when the params are ints, each gets boxed to be a reference 
type, while int[] is already a reference type

Answer (score 2):

```
    Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
```

1 2 3 are autoboxed to Integer objects which are then placed in an Object[]

```
    Arrays.asList(new int[]{1, 2, 3});
```

forces the 3 integers into a primitive int array.

`Arrays.asList()` expects `Object[]`, so it places your `int[]` array into a single element `Object[]`

Comment: "Arrays.asList() expects Object[]" or `T[]` for any reference type `T`

Comment: agreed. the winning answer explains it in better detail than me. the answer didn't exist when i wrote mine. <sobs uncontrollably>